# Can't understand the output sequence, using Scanner & FileReader to read a text file & print

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a simple text file of book list with book name & author separated by "-". Using scanner, file reader and skip to separate the book name from author and print it. I am unable to understand the program flow at output:

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class FileReaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        File file = new File("Filepath....>BookList.txt");
        Scanner scan = null;

        try {
                scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                scan.useDelimiter("-");

                while(scan.hasNext())
                {
                    System.out.println("Book -> "+scan.next());
                    scan.skip(scan.delimiter());
                    System.out.println("Author -> "+scan.next());

                }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scan.close();       


}
}
```

The text file contains the following:

```
Harry Potter & Order of Phoenix - J K Rowling
Autobiography of a Yogi - Parmahansa Yoganand
Alice in Wonderland - Lewis Carroll
```

The output is as follows:

```
Book -> Harry Potter & Order of Phoenix 
Author ->  J K Rowling
Autobiography of a Yogi 
Book ->  Parmahansa Yoganand
Alice in Wonderland 
Author ->  Lewis Carroll
```

What I am unable to comprehend is, First book is printing fine, how does the second book name gets printed without "Book->" or any println statement in front of it and then again third book gets printed and finally the author with last part ?

Answer (score 1):

When you set delimiter to `-`, then **only** `-` delimits tokens, newlines don't, which is why the second token is the text `"J K Rowling\nAutobiography of a Yogi"`.

If you want to delimit at both `-` and newlines, use regex `"-|\\R"`.

You also want to remove the spaces around the `-`, so make that part of the delimiter, or call `trim()` on the returned strings.

*Demo*

```java
String input = "Harry Potter & Order of Phoenix - J K Rowling\r\n" + 
               "Autobiography of a Yogi - Parmahansa Yoganand\r\n" + 
               "Alice in Wonderland - Lewis Carroll\r\n";
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(input)) {
    scan.useDelimiter("\\s*-\\s*|\\s*\\R");
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Book -> " + scan.next());
        System.out.println("Author -> " + scan.next());
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Book -> Harry Potter & Order of Phoenix
Author -> J K Rowling
Book -> Autobiography of a Yogi
Author -> Parmahansa Yoganand
Book -> Alice in Wonderland
Author -> Lewis Carroll
```

Answer (score 1):

With `scan.useDelimiter("-")` you are tokenizing the strings of your source file without considering the newline characters.

I would change approach and use `.nextLine()` method in place of `.next()` and then split the line with `.split("-")` method of String.

Alternatively, you can set the Scanner delimiter to

```
scan.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? i tried this: while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
     System.out.println("Book -> "+scan.nextLine());
     scan.nextLine().split("-");
     System.out.println("Author -> "+scan.nextLine());
     
    } doesnt work

Comment: Here there is:

`File file = new File("<path>");
Scanner scan = null;

try {
    scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] elems = line.split("-");
        System.out.println("Book -> " + elems[0].trim());
        System.out.println("Author -> " + elems[1].trim());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`